# GCHandle.IsAllocated does not return false for weak handle to destroyed object

Tags: c++-cli

In some C++/CLI code I have a native class which has a factory method `GetWrapper()` for creating its own managed .NET wrapper object. Internally, it holds a weak reference to its wrapper via GCHandle. When `GetWrapper()` is called, the GCHandle is checked and either a handle to the existing wrapper is returned, or (if it does not point to an object anymore, because the old wrapper object has been destroyed by the Garbage Collector) a new one is created an returned.

```
// .h
class NativeClass
{
public:
    WrapperClass^ GetWrapper();
private:
    WrapperClass^ GetNewWrapper();
    GCHandle m_wrapperGCHandle;
};

// .cpp
WrapperClass^ NativeClass::GetWrapper()
{
    if(m_wrapperGCHandle.IsAllocated)
    {
        try
        {
            WrapperClass^ wrapper = nullptr;
            wrapper = dynamic_cast<WrapperClass^>(wrapperGCHandle.Target);

            if(wrapper == nullptr)
            {
                return GetNewWrapper();
            }
            else
            {
                return wrapper;
            }
         }
         catch(System::InvalidOperationException^)
         {
             return GetNewWrapper();
         }
    else
    {
        return GetNewWrapper();
    }
}

WrapperClass^ NativeClass::GetNewWrapper()
{
    WrapperClass^ wrapper = gcnew WrapperClass(/*some args*/);
    m_wrapperGCHandle = GCHandle::Alloc(wrapper, GCHandleType::Weak);
}
```

The strange thing now is that `m_wrapperGCHandle.IsAllocated` **always** returns true, even if the wrapper has been garbage-collected. The MSDN [tells](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.gchandle.isallocated.aspx) to "Use this property when using Weak handles to determine if the GCHandle is still available.". But it's always true. If it's not available then the Target is a nullptr instead.

Am I missing something or is the MSDN wrong?

Comment: There is an implicit threading-race in your code.  The GC may run right after you tested IsAllocated.

Comment: @HansPassant Yes, it's currently not thread-safe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My read of the MSDN doco is that `m_wrapprGCHandle.IsAllocated` will return true until `m_wrapperGCHandle.Free` is called - the `IsAllocated` property is checking for the state of the handle rather than the state of the reference held by the handle.

As you have noted, `m_wrapperGCHandle.Target` is null when the object has been garbage collected. I have used a similar method to what you have in your example code to generate managed wrapper classes, and I always check to see if `Target` is null and regenerate the wrapper object if `Target` is null.

Also, a suggestion ... it looks to me as if you have a handle leak in your code because you are calling `GCHandle::Alloc` without a corresponding `m_wrapperGCHandle.Free` call. Try putting the call to `Alloc` in the class constructor and the call to `Free` in the destructor:

```
NativeClass::NativeClass()
{
    m_wrapperGCHandle = GCHandle::Alloc(nullptr, GCHandleType::Weak);
}

NativeClass::~NativeClass()
{
    m_wrapperGCHandle.Free();
}
```

then your `GetNewWrapper` method is simply:

```
WrapperClass^ NativeClass::GetNewWrapper()
{
    m_wrapperGCHandle.Target = gcnew WrapperClass(/*some args*/);
}
```

and you can remove the `if(m_wrapperGCHandle.IsAllocated) - else` chain from the `GetWrapper` method.